# javascript function replace wont work , why?

Tags: javascript, replace

why javascript function replace wont work ?

```
    social_share: function(e){

        var is_video,
            social_name = $(e).attr('class'),
            share_url = document.URL,
            share_title = $('title').text(),
            share_media,
            share;

        switch(social_name) {

            case 'twitter':
                share = 'https://twitter.com/share?url={share_url}&text={share_title}';
            break;

            case 'facebook':
                share = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link={share_url}&picture={share_media}&name={share_title}';
            break;

            case 'google':
                share = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url={share_url}';
            break;

            case 'pinterest':
                share = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media={share_media}&url={share_url}&is_video={is_video}&description={share_title}';
            break;

            case 'mailto':
                share = '...';
            break;

        }

        share.replace('{share_title}', share_title)
             .replace('{share_url}', encodeURI(share_url))
             .replace('{share_media}', encodeURI(share_media))
             .replace('{is_video}', is_video);

        console.log(share);

    },
```

and console.log function return string share without any replaces...
it would by https://twitter.com/share?url={share_url}&text={share_title} if twitter , and same other's

Comment: and how about function encodeURI , it's good for urls for social shares ?

Comment: out of interest, how did you know about the `replace` function in the first place? Just wondering what source you have seen that doesn't show you the correct way to use it

Comment: its was my mistake , i didn't see it , need some rest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will return the new value back, so you need to save it to the variable:

```
share = share.replace( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in javascript. So changing the string by any of the string function will return a new string as the output. In the above code change the syntax as :

```
share = share.replace('{share_title}', share_title);
```